# How do I write regex pattern to validate netmask?

Tags: regex

I need help to write a regex for accepting IPv6 subnet from 8000:: to ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff. The subnet is based on the prefix range between /1 - 128

Example list of valid netmask for IPv6:

```
The prefix /1 is equal to netmask 8000::
The prefix /2 is equal to netmask c000::
The prefix /3 is equal to netmask e000::
The prefix /4 is equal to netmask f000::
The prefix /5 is equal to netmask f800::
The prefix /6 is equal to netmask fc00::
The prefix /7 is equal to netmask fe00::
The prefix /8 is equal to netmask ff00::
The prefix /9 is equal to netmask ff80::
The prefix /10 is equal to netmask ffc0::
The prefix /11 is equal to netmask ffe0::
The prefix /12 is equal to netmask fff0::
The prefix /13 is equal to netmask fff8::
The prefix /14 is equal to netmask fffc::
The prefix /15 is equal to netmask fffe::
The prefix /16 is equal to netmask ffff::
The prefix /17 is equal to netmask ffff:8000::
The prefix /18 is equal to netmask ffff:c000::
The prefix /19 is equal to netmask ffff:e000::
The prefix /20 is equal to netmask ffff:f000::
The prefix /21 is equal to netmask ffff:f800::
The prefix /22 is equal to netmask ffff:fc00::
The prefix /23 is equal to netmask ffff:fe00::
The prefix /24 is equal to netmask ffff:ff00::
The prefix /25 is equal to netmask ffff:ff80::
The prefix /26 is equal to netmask ffff:ffc0::
The prefix /27 is equal to netmask ffff:ffe0::
The prefix /28 is equal to netmask ffff:fff0::
The prefix /29 is equal to netmask ffff:fff8::
The prefix /30 is equal to netmask ffff:fffc::
The prefix /31 is equal to netmask ffff:fffe::
The prefix /32 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff::
The prefix /33 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:8000::
The prefix /34 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:c000::
The prefix /35 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:e000::
The prefix /36 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:f000::
The prefix /37 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:f800::
The prefix /38 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:fc00::
The prefix /39 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:fe00::
The prefix /40 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ff00::
The prefix /41 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ff80::
The prefix /42 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffc0::
The prefix /43 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffe0::
The prefix /44 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:fff0::
The prefix /45 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:fff8::
The prefix /46 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:fffc::
The prefix /47 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:fffe::
The prefix /48 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff::
The prefix /49 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:8000::
The prefix /50 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:c000::
The prefix /51 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:e000::
The prefix /52 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:f000::
The prefix /53 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:f800::
The prefix /54 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:fc00::
The prefix /55 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:fe00::
The prefix /56 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ff00::
The prefix /57 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80::
The prefix /58 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffc0::
The prefix /59 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffe0::
The prefix /60 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:fff0::
The prefix /61 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:fff8::
The prefix /62 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:fffc::
The prefix /63 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:fffe::
The prefix /64 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
The prefix /65 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:8000::
The prefix /66 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:c000::
The prefix /67 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:e000::
The prefix /68 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f000::
The prefix /69 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f800::
The prefix /70 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fc00::
The prefix /71 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fe00::
The prefix /72 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff00::
The prefix /73 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80::
The prefix /74 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffc0::
The prefix /75 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffe0::
The prefix /76 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff0::
The prefix /77 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff8::
The prefix /78 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffc::
The prefix /79 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffe::
The prefix /80 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
The prefix /81 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:8000::
The prefix /82 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:c000::
The prefix /83 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:e000::
The prefix /84 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f000::
The prefix /85 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f800::
The prefix /86 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fc00::
The prefix /87 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fe00::
The prefix /88 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff00::
The prefix /89 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80::
The prefix /90 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffc0::
The prefix /91 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffe0::
The prefix /92 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff0::
The prefix /93 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff8::
The prefix /94 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffc::
The prefix /95 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffe::
The prefix /96 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
The prefix /97 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:8000:0
The prefix /98 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:c000:0
The prefix /99 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:e000:0
The prefix /100 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f000:0
The prefix /101 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f800:0
The prefix /102 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fc00:0
The prefix /103 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fe00:0
The prefix /104 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff00:0
The prefix /105 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80:0
The prefix /106 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffc0:0
The prefix /107 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffe0:0
The prefix /108 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff0:0
The prefix /109 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff8:0
The prefix /110 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffc:0
The prefix /111 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffe:0
The prefix /112 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:0
The prefix /113 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:8000
The prefix /114 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:c000
The prefix /115 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:e000
The prefix /116 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f000
The prefix /117 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f800
The prefix /118 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fc00
The prefix /119 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fe00
The prefix /120 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff00
The prefix /121 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80
The prefix /122 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffc0
The prefix /123 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffe0
The prefix /124 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff0
The prefix /125 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff8
The prefix /126 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffc
The prefix /127 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffe
The last prefix /128 is equal to netmask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
```

That means regex should only match any input from the above list.

I came across this post, [Regex pattern for IPv6 netmask from for a given prefix /1 - /128](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74918356/regex-pattern-for-ipv6-netmask-from-for-a-given-prefix-1-128)
The answer provided by @trincot seems to be working but with 2 different regex.

Is there any way we can combine this logic in one regex?

Comment: What language/tool/platform/framework are you using? There might be a better way than using regex to parse those IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the 2 regex of @trincot melted using 2 lookahead:

```
(?=^(?:(?:[^:]{4}:){1,6}:|(?:[^:]{4}:){7}(?:0|[^:]{4}))$)(?=^[fF:]*[8cCeEfF]0*(?::[0:])?$).+$
```

This ending part **.+$** is optional. It just catches until the end of line/string if the 2 lookahead are matching to the end of line/string. Meaning a lines/strings like this one will match:

```
8000::
c000::
e000::
f000::
f800::
fc00::
fe00::
ff00::
ff80::
ffe0::
fff0::
fffc::
fffe::
ffff::
ffff:8000::
ffff:c000::
ffff:e000::
ffff:f000::
ffff:f800::
ffff:fc00::
ffff:fe00::
ffff:ff00::
ffff:ff80::
ffff:ffc0::
ffff:ffe0::
ffff:fff0::
ffff:fff8::
ffff:fffc::
ffff:fffe::
ffff:ffff::
ffff:ffff:8000::
ffff:ffff:c000::
ffff:ffff:e000::
ffff:ffff:f000::
ffff:ffff:f800::
ffff:ffff:fc00::
ffff:ffff:fe00::
ffff:ffff:ff00::
ffff:ffff:ff80::
ffff:ffff:ffc0::
ffff:ffff:ffe0::
ffff:ffff:fff0::
ffff:ffff:fff8::
ffff:ffff:fffc::
ffff:ffff:fffe::
ffff:ffff:ffff::
ffff:ffff:ffff:8000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:c000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:e000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:f000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:f800::
ffff:ffff:ffff:fc00::
ffff:ffff:ffff:fe00::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ff00::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffc0::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffe0::
ffff:ffff:ffff:fff0::
ffff:ffff:ffff:fff8::
ffff:ffff:ffff:fffc::
ffff:ffff:ffff:fffe::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:8000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:c000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:e000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f800::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fc00::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fe00::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff00::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffc0::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffe0::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff0::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff8::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffc::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffe::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:8000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:c000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:e000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f800::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fc00::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fe00::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff00::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffc0::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffe0::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff0::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff8::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffc::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffe::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:8000:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:c000:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:e000:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f000:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f800:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fc00:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fe00:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff00:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffc0:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffe0:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff0:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff8:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffc:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffe:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:8000
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:c000
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:e000
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f000
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f800
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fc00
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fe00
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff00
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffc0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffe0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff8
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffc
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffe
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
```

And a lines/strings like below will not:

```
ff80:: blabliblo.
something ff80::
```

Finally, just be aware that I didn't full tested the 2 regex of @trincot.

Comment: I guess you could even use just one lookahead and match the other pattern normally (see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/sBR85S/1)).