# How to write regex to validate ipv6 netmask in goLang?

Tags: regex, go

I need to write regex validation for netmask in Ipv6 form.

List of valid netmask for IPv6:

```
8000::
c000::
e000::
f000::
f800::
fc00::
fe00::
ff00::
ff80::
ffc0::
ffe0::
fff0::
fff8::
fffc::
fffe::
ffff::
ffff:8000::
ffff:c000::
ffff:e000::
ffff:f000::
ffff:f800::
ffff:fc00::
ffff:fe00::
ffff:ff00::
ffff:ff80::
ffff:ffc0::
ffff:ffe0::
ffff:fff0::
ffff:fff8::
ffff:fffc::
ffff:fffe::
ffff:ffff::
ffff:ffff:8000::
ffff:ffff:c000::
ffff:ffff:e000::
ffff:ffff:f000::
ffff:ffff:f800::
ffff:ffff:fc00::
ffff:ffff:fe00::
ffff:ffff:ff00::
ffff:ffff:ff80::
ffff:ffff:ffc0::
ffff:ffff:ffe0::
ffff:ffff:fff0::
ffff:ffff:fff8::
ffff:ffff:fffc::
ffff:ffff:fffe::
ffff:ffff:ffff::
ffff:ffff:ffff:8000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:c000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:e000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:f000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:f800::
ffff:ffff:ffff:fc00::
ffff:ffff:ffff:fe00::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ff00::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffc0::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffe0::
ffff:ffff:ffff:fff0::
ffff:ffff:ffff:fff8::
ffff:ffff:ffff:fffc::
ffff:ffff:ffff:fffe::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:8000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:c000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:e000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f800::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fc00::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fe00::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff00::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffc0::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffe0::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff0::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff8::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffc::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffe::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:8000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:c000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:e000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f000::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f800::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fc00::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fe00::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff00::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffc0::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffe0::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff0::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff8::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffc::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffe::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:8000:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:c000:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:e000:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f000:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f800:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fc00:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fe00:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff00:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffc0:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffe0:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff0:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff8:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffc:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffe:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:8000
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:c000
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:e000
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f000
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:f800
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fc00
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fe00
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff00
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff80
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffc0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffe0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff8
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffc
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffe
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
```

Is there any way we can have one single regex that can help me here?

I have been going through a bunch of stack overflow posts for this:

- [Regex pattern for IPv6 netmask from for a given prefix /1 - /128](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74918356/regex-pattern-for-ipv6-netmask-from-for-a-given-prefix-1-128)
- [How do I write regex pattern to validate netmask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77104469/how-do-i-write-regex-pattern-to-validate-netmask)

I gained some understanding of how to do this with 2 separate regex here.
If we can combine the below 2 regex in one it will solve this problem.

1. A pattern for ensuring the input consists of a series of colons and F's, followed by one of "8CEF", followed by a series of zeroes, possibly followed by "::" or by ":0"

> `^[fF:]*[8cCeEfF]0*(?::[0:])?$`

2. A pattern that requires that colons appear at fixed positions, and only there:

> `^(?:(?:[^:]{4}:){1,6}:|(?:[^:]{4}:){7}(?:0|[^:]{4}))$`

We can combine this with Lookahead but unfortunately, lookahead is not supported in go.

Is there any other way to combine these 2 regex in one?
Or is there any other way we can achieve this?

Comment: I tried around with it, here is my latest attempt: [`^(?:(?:[fF]{4}:){0,5}(?:[fF]{3}[8cCeEfF0]|[fF]{2}[8cCeEfF]0|[fF][8cCeEfF]00|[8cCeEfF]000)::|(?:(?:[fF]{4}:){6}(?:(?:[fF]{3}[8cCeEfF0]|[fF]{2}[8cCeEfF]0|[fF][8cCeEfF]00|[8cCeEfF]000):0|[fF]{4}:(?:[fF]{3}[8cCeEfF0]|[fF]{2}[8cCeEfF]0|[fF][8cCeEfF]00|[8cCeEfF]000))))$`](https://regex101.com/r/Xj6v4c/4)

Answer (score 1):

This will match the entire address: [`(?i)^(?:(?:f{4}:){0,6}f{0,3}[8cef]0{0,3}::|(?:f{4}:){6}f{0,3}[8cef]0{0,3}:0|(?:f{4}:){7}f{0,3}[8cef]0{0,3})$`](https://regex101.com/r/gYCwcu/2)

#### Explanation

Based on your input, you have 3 cases each using a potential `ffff:` sequence prefix:

1. A short address ending in `::`

   - Capture the prefix up to 6 times followed by `f*[8cef]0*` sequence terminating in `::`.
2. A full address ending in `:0`

   - Capture the prefix exactly 6 times followed by `f*[8cef]0*` terminating in `:0`. This won't match `8000:0`.
3. A full address

   - Capture the prefix exactly 7 times terminating in a `f*[8cef]0*` sequence.

#### Breakdown

`(?i)` = Case insensitive search.

`^$` = Match the entire string.

`(?:)` = Non-capture group.

`()|()|()` = Alternate on the 3 cases described above.

`(?:f{4}:){0,6}f{0,3}[8cef]0{0,3}::` = Case 1

- `(?:f{4}:){0,6}` = The prefix up to 6 times.
- `f{0,3}[8cef]0{0,3}` = At most 3 `f` digits, 1 `[8cef]` digit, at most 3 `0` digits.

  - `(?:fff[8cef]|ff[8cef]0|f[8cef]00|[8cef]000)` = Incorporating [@bobble bubble's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble) comment, this would ensure exactly 4 digits surrounded by `f`'s and `0`'s. Substitute this in each of the cases referenced below as well.
- `::` = Terminating sequence.

`(?:f{4}:){6}f{0,3}[8cef]0{0,3}:0` = Case 2

- `(?:f{4}:){6}` = The prefix exactly 6 times.
- `f{0,3}[8cef]0{0,3}` = Same as above.
- `:0` = Terminating sequence.

`(?:f{4}:){7}f{0,3}[8cef]0{0,3}` = Case 3

- `(?:f{4}:){7}` = The prefix exactly 7 times.
- `f{0,3}[8cef]0{0,3}` = Same as above.

#### Notes

- I've opted for specific ranges `{x,y}` instead of `*` to at least prevent an infinite amount of matches.
- You won't be able to limit sequences to 4 digits without breaking your pattern of `[8cef]` surrounded by optional `f`'s and `0`'s. Regex can't dynamically adjust the length of part of the pattern. Alternation would need to be used for each case type.
- If you opt for using so many alternations, it'd be best to split the regex up into string variables and then concatenate all of the parts together to keep things clear.

Comment: Thank you for your response on this. However, the regex suggested by you does match with Invalid IP addresses as well like '8000:0' This is clearly an invalid IPv6 address and hence should not be accepted as a valid netmask. That's why I am looking for something that can combine both of the above-mentioned regexes. i.e. It should match this string as well as all ':' must be at the right place

Comment: also, This is matchig with something like 8800:0 (because of [08cef]{3} ) , this is also not valid netmask and should not be accepted.

Comment: @RupeshChoudhary I updated my answer. I need to stress that regex can't dynamically check a string based on the surrounding characters without making the pattern explode in size with either look arounds or alternations. The `f*[8cef]0*` pattern in your question will still match something like `ffffffff8000000`. To ensure it only matches 4 digits would require a bunch of alternation on each possible combo of `f`'s and `0`'s surrounding the single `[8cef]` digit.

Comment: @zecuse The reason that I listed all the options is because if you use e.g. `f{0,3}[8cef]0{0,3}` this could also match something like [`fffc000`](https://regex101.com/r/4fsQli/1) or even [`c`](https://regex101.com/r/n0vGbN/1) which might be undesired. Though if using `i`-flag this part could be shortened to e.g. `(?:f{3}[8cef0]|f{2}[8cef]0|f[8cef]00|[8cef]000)` not sure if there is a better option for this.